# How to get key value from query string from SharePoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, query-string

I have an url: `http://test?ID=i:0#.w|pro\administrator`

I would like to get the current user (from Sharepoint) with c# code.

So I used the QueryString, here is:

```
private string userLogin = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ID"];
```

But the problem is that the value returned by QueryString is `i:0`.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that's what your URL has specified the value of the `ID` parameter is.  `#` is a special character in URLs and everything after it is a separate part of the URL.  You should URL encode the value of the parameter when constructing the URL in the first place to ensure that `#` (and any other characters) are treated as characters in value of the `ID` query parameter.

Comment: Thanks for reply. And is there a solution without changing this url?

Comment: @Jayce No, you have a broken URL.  You need to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get current user, why do not use SP native method:

```
SPWeb web = SPControl.GetContextWeb(SPContext.Current);       
uName = web.CurrentUser.ID;
```